# Multiple classes refering eachother in multiple header files

Tags: c++, class, header-files

My game has a Player class which is a player, controlled by the user and it will wield a weapon. The weapon class is in a different header file but contains a reference to the player, so it can tell the Player class what animation it has to use.

Now my question:
It seems that im doing something wrong with referencing to eachother. I have created a forward decleration in both header files, but i get an error: "incomplete type not allowed"

I also get `"cannot convert from Player* const to Weapon"` because i use this: `m_weapon(Weapon(this))`, that was a tryout to solve the problem.

my files:

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "DrawableObject.h"
#include "PlayerState.h"

class Weapon;

class Player : public AnimatableObject
{
private:
    std::string m_name; //name of the player
    States::PlayerState m_state; //state of the player
    Weapon &m_weapon;
public:
    Player(std::string name): 
    AnimatableObject("../../Images/PlayerSheet.png",
    sf::Vector2i(64,64),sf::Vector2i(8,8)),
    m_name(name),
    m_weapon(Weapon(this))
{
    m_updateTime = 100;
}

//Update the Player
virtual void Update() override;

};
#endif
```

Weapon.h

```
#ifndef WEAPON
#define WEAPON

#include "DrawableObject.h"

class Player;

class Weapon : AnimatableObject
{
protected:
float m_cooldown;
Player *m_user;
public:
Weapon(Player *user):m_cooldown(0.0f),
       m_user(user),
       AnimatableObject("",sf::Vector2i(0,0),sf::Vector2i(0,0))
    {}
Weapon(Player *user, float f):
       m_cooldown(f),
       AnimatableObject("",sf::Vector2i(0,0),sf::Vector2i(0,0)), 
       m_user(user)
    {}
virtual void Use(){} //Left Click/Trigger
virtual void AltUse(){} //Right Click/Trigger

};
#endif WEAPON
```

So how do i refer to eachother and dealing with the header files?

PS. im using Visual Studio 2012 if it helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

```
m_weapon(Weapon(this))
```

When you do it, you're trying to construct a new `Weapon` object. But at this stage, it has not been defined yet (only forward declared). Try moving the constructor's implementation to your .cpp file, where you have included the `Weapon.h` file.

Anothre problem is that `m_weapon` is a reference to a `Weapon` object. When you do `m_weapon(Weapon(this))`, you're trying to contruct a new object, pass a reference to it and immediately destroy it, as it's a temporary. You can't do that.

What you can do is change `m_weapon` to be a pointer and initialise it with `new Weapon(this)`. You then have to remember to destroy it in Player's destructor.

I this scenario it is important to establish which object owns the other. I this case Player would own the Weapon object and it would be it's duty to manage it (delete when appropriate).